# How to use Mongoose to connect mongo-atlas db?

Tags: mongodb-atlas

I'm following this tutorial to setup the mongo atlas db.

https://developerhandbook.com/mongodb/connect-mongo-atlas-mongoose/

But on the setup of connection, I got error like

```
(node:60566) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: user is not allowed to do action [find] on [admin.sample_airbnb]
    at queryCallback (/Users/jay.lin/dev/graphql-playlist/server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:223:25)
    at /Users/jay.lin/dev/graphql-playlist/server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:541:18
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
(node:60566) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:60566) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

It seems atlas db is using "admin" collection by default, how can I change it to "sample_airbnb" collection?

```
    const connector = mongoose.connect(
        'mongodb+srv://test:<password>@cluster0-ppeaz.mongodb.net/a?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
    )
    .then(() => {
        // connector.useDb('sample_airbnb?');
        const Listing = mongoose.model(
            'listingsAndReviews',
            new mongoose.Schema({
                name: String,
                summary: String,
            }),
            'sample_airbnb'
        );
        Listing.findOne({}).then((r) => {
            console.log(r);
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

(node:60566) You need to add "admin permission"s to be able to query the db. This will be under "security" tab then "Database Access". "Add new user" button (which is then used in your connection string).

".mongodb.net/a?" needs to be ".mongodb.net/sample_airbnb?"

(node:60566) Use try catch e.g.

```
const connector = mongoose.connect(
        'mongodb+srv://test:<password>@cluster0-ppeaz.mongodb.net/sample_airbnb?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
    )
    .then(() => {
        // connector.useDb('sample_airbnb?');
      const Listing = mongoose.model(
          'listingsAndReviews',
           new mongoose.Schema({
                name: String,
                summary: String,
           }),
          'sample_airbnb'
        );
    try {
        const listings = await Listing.findOne({});
        res.json(listings);
      } catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: err });
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why does this create a "test" database instead of the "sample_airbnb"?